# How to get a full native path of the file in String format which is being uploaded

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

How to get a full native path of the file in String format which is being uploaded using   and being used in a manged bean for its validation and upload? I also don't really want to use simple mode for p:fileUpload. 
For example, if a file is being uploaded is from desktop then I want the path of the file as "C:\Users\\Desktop\" in a String format.

Any help would be really appreciated...

Comment: There are about a dozen questions and answers in stackoverflow about this subject. I'm curious to what search terms you used and not finding any. I can then improve one of the duplicates so it might get found with your search criteria as well. Answer: you can't, not even in plain html.

Comment: why is everybody just upvoting the possible duplicate comment instead of actually press the close button and mark it as a duplicate...

Comment: @Kukeltje Possibly they have run out of close votes?

Answer (score -1):

you can use java.nio.file.Path library

`Path path = Paths.get("test.txt"); 
log("Path: " + path);
log("Absolute: " + path.isAbsolute());`

Comment: This would be the **server side** path, not the client-side one...you cannot  (and should not) run java in a browser anymore